# Multiply by 0 optimization

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Suppose i have:

```
double f(const double *r) {
    return 0*(r[0]*r[1]);
}
```

should compiler be able to optimize out the segment, or does it still have to perform operation, in case the values might be inf or nan?

```
gcc -O3 -S test.c:

        .file   "test.c"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movsd   (%rdi), %xmm0
        mulsd   8(%rdi), %xmm0
        mulsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   f, .-f
        .section        .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
        .align 8
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

seems no elimination?

aha:

```
gcc -O3  -ffast-math  -S test.c

        .file   "test.c"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorpd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   f, .-f
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It isn't only `inf` and `NaN` that prevent the optimization there, it's also the sign - `0.0` * something negative is `-0.0`, otherwise it's `0.0`, so you actually have to compute the sign of `r[0]*r[1]`.

Answer (score 13):

Depends on whether the compiler implements IEEE754. Neither C nor C++ requires that a compiler supports `NaN`, but IEEE754 does.

Comment: It's not just `NaN`. In IEEE 754, the result of `0.0*x` depends on the sign of `x`.